# How can I make many to many relational tables nullable in Prisma?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have these tables:

```
model User {
  @@map("user")
  id             Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName      String    @map("first_name")
  lastName       String    @map("last_name")
  followers      Follows[] @relation("following")
  following      Follows[] @relation("followers")
}
model Follows {
  @@id([followerId, followingId])
  followerId  Int
  followingId Int
  follower    User @relation("followers", references: [id], fields: [followerId])
  following   User @relation("following", references: [id], fields: [followingId])
  status      FollowStatus
}
```

User can follow somebodies and can be followed, so User and User must have many-to-many relationship. And Follows is the relation table of them.

And I want to make the fields `followers` and `following` nullable. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `followerId` and `followingId` as nullable if you introduce an id column in the `Follows` model, which is not dependent on `followerId` and `followingId`.

Here's an example:

```
model User {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String    @map("first_name")
  lastName  String    @map("last_name")
  followers Follows[] @relation("following")
  following Follows[] @relation("followers")

  @@map("user")
}

model Follows {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  followerId  Int?
  followingId Int?
  follower    User?        @relation("followers", references: [id], fields: [followerId])
  following   User?        @relation("following", references: [id], fields: [followingId])
  status      FollowStatus
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for late reply. Thank your for your answer!